# Retreiving a Map<Object ,List<Object Line Items>> from a apex controller to lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, map

Hi I have an object as Product and another object as   Product Line items.
What I am trying to do is fetch data from my Apex Controller in the form of Map which has Product as key and List of Line Items as values .
`Map<Product__c,List<Product_Line_Items__c>>`

The problem is the way I am getting the map in Lightning component is (which I am seeing through console log )

[image]

The requirement is to iterate the map and get header object so that I can display the field values like below

[image]

So now in lightning component's controller this is the way I am fetching this map from apex controller

```javascript
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    console.log(state);
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var result =response.getReturnValue().mapProductToSKU;
        for(var key in result){

            arrayMapP.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
        } 
        component.set("v.ProducttoSKU",arrayMapP);
```

Now in component

```xml
<aura:attribute name="PNumbertoSKU" type="Map" /> 
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.PNumbertoSKU}" var="PNumber1">
PNumber1.key.field name
```

Here I am seeing data in this way

[Product__c (Product....]
I am not seeing that particular field value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend refactoring your Apex method to return the data in a different format.

For example, you could return a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` where the outer map is keyed on the product ID and the inner map contains keys like `product` (where the value is the `Product__c` object) and `lineItems` (whose value is a `List<Product_Line_Items__c>`).

Then your data will look more like this -- and you'll be better able to use it:

```js
{
  blmK0000003Saaaaa: {
    product: {
      Id: "blmK0000003Saaaaa",
      Product_Description__c: "Product1",
      Quantity__c: 1,
      Total_Sales_Price__c: 2858.07
    },
    lineItems: [
      {
        Id: "blmK0000003xxxxx",
        Name: "SKU1",
        Quantity__c: 2,
        Total_Sales_Price__c: 6443.32,
      },
      {
        Id: "blmK0000003yyyyy",
        Name: "SKU1",
        Quantity__c: 2,
        Total_Sales_Price__c: 6443.32,
      }
    ]
  },
  blmK0000003Sbbbbb: {
    product: {
      Id: "blmK0000003Sbbbbb",
      Product_Description__c: "Product2",
      Quantity__c: 1,
      Total_Sales_Price__c: 2858.07
    },
    lineItems: [
      {
        Id: "blmK0000003zzzzz",
        Name: "SKU1",
        Quantity__c: 2,
        Total_Sales_Price__c: 6443.32,
      }
    ]
  },
  // etc...
}
```